How to get logs from MobileVLCKit's VLCMediaPlayer (iOS)?
I am having issues with streaming FLV files with VLCKit on iOS. Logs from the player would be helpful for debugging.

It was a pretty obscure example of adding VLC logs here. You can setup a logger for your VLCMediaPlayer like so:
let logger = VLCConsoleLogger()
logger.level = .info
logger.formatter.contextFlags = .levelContextModule
player.libraryInstance.loggers = [logger]

